# ¿Como limitar la cantidad de decimales de un double?

Tags: java

Como el titulo dice, quiero limitar la cantidad de decimales que resulta de una operación con variables tipo double, este resultado se muestra en un JTextArea de un JFrame.

El codigo que hace la operacion e imprime el resultado en el JTextArea es el siguiente: (`la`, `lb` y `lc` representan los lados de un triangulo, `a` calcula el area y `A` es el JTextArea donde se imprime el resultado).

```
if (lb+lc>la && la+lc>lb && la+lb>lc){
     a=Math.sqrt((la+lb+lc)*(-la+lb+lc)*(la-lb+lc)*(la+lb-lc)/16);
     p=la+lb+lc;
     A.setText("El triangulo es "+t+".\nEl area es ("+a+").\nEl perimetro es ("+p+").");
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Existe muchas formas de limitar la cantidad de decimales de **salida (Presentación)** de un `double` , más no del número en si , por ejemplo para  `double number = 1.4159999999;` limitar la salida a  **2** decimales.  si usted desea más dígitos  es cuestión de añadir ceros en `decimalformat` y `Round, cambiar el 2 por por la cantidad deseada en`String.format`y`printf`Y   y en`setScale`de`BigDecimal`

1. Usando [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

   ```
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
    System.out.println(df.format(number));
    /* Salida : 1.42*/
   ```
2. Usando [String.Format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

   ```
   System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", number));
   /* Salida : 1.42*/
   ```
3. Si solo desea a que la salida tenga ese formato aplicaría  [numberformat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)

   ```
   System.out.printf("Valor: %.2f", number ); 
   /* Salida : 1.42*/
   ```
4. Mediante [Math.Round()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(double)) donde la cantidad de ceros es la cantidad de decimales a limitar

   ```
   System.out.println((double)Math.round(number * 100d) / 100d);
    /* Salida : 1.42*/
   ```
5. Usando la clase [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) , usando el método [setScale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale(int,%20int)) que recibe dos parámetros la cantidad de decimales a limitar y el modo de redondeo

   ```
   BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(number);
   bd = bd.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
   System.out.println(bd.doubleValue());
   /* Salida 1.42*/
   ```

Comment: *Existe muchas formas de limitar la cantidad de decimales de un double* técnicamente **no**, no existen maneras de quitar decimales a un `double`, lo que puedes hacer es cambiar **el formato de presentación** de los tipos de punto flotante, pero no puedes reducir sus decimales. Si quieres reducir decimales y redondear y operaciones con este tipo de resultados, deberás usar `BigDecimal` o alguna clase similar.

Answer (score 9):

Prueba utilizando String.format

```
double valor = 123.456789;

String.format("%.3f", valor)  // 123.456
```

Puedes combinarlo todo así, para este caso es una forma compacta y que te permite dar formato a todo junto en una sola linea.

```
String.format("El triangulo es %s.\nEl area es (%.3f).\nEl perimetro es (%.3f).", t, a, p)
```

Ten en cuenta que format toma la automáticamente la configuración de locale, por lo tanto dependiendo del pais, puede usar `.` o `,` como separador de decimales.

Answer (score 4):

Puedes usar un [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html). Por ejemplo:

```
DecimalFormat formato = new DecimalFormat("#.000");

System.out.println(formato.format(p));
```

Te devolverá tu valor con tres decimales. Tendrías que añadir (o quitar) tantos ceros como decimales quieras después del número entero.

Answer (score 2):

Lo mejor que e encontrado para reducir la cantidad de decimales de un double:

numero: el valor con todos los decimales

numeroDecimales: cuantos decimales quiero recuperar

Ejem: 2.8049999999999997 devuelve 2.805

double val = formatearDecimales( 2.8049999999999997, 3);

```
public static Double formatearDecimales(Double numero, Integer numeroDecimales) {
return Math.round(numero * Math.pow(10, numeroDecimales)) / Math.pow(10, numeroDecimales);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres limitar la cantidad de decimales sin redondear, lo puede hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
Double answer = 234.32545;
BigDecimal formatNumber = new BigDecimal(answer);
formatNumber = formatNumber.setScale(2, RoundingMode.DOWN);
System.out.println(formatNumber); // 234.32
```