# Duda con decimales Android (BigDecimal)

Tags: java, android, bigdecimal

Cuando hago una cuenta para sacar el *%* de un número, tengo un problema, me explico:

Saco el *5%* de *7.74* y es **0.3870** pero yo quiero que solamente me muestre dos números en la parte decimal, es decir **0.38** ¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

Y otra duda que tengo ¿es posible que el resultado sea con una **,** y no un **.**?

Así es como realizo el proceso:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText uno;
    TextView tres;
    Button btn1;

    static final BigDecimal PORCENTAJE_CINCO = new BigDecimal("0.05");

    public BigDecimal calculaCincoPorCiento(BigDecimal numero) {
        return numero.multiply(PORCENTAJE_CINCO);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        uno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uno);
        tres = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tres);

        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                BigDecimal aux0 = new BigDecimal(uno.getText().toString());
                BigDecimal aux1 = calculaCincoPorCiento(aux0);
                tres.setText(aux1 + " " + "es el 5%");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Gracias!

Comment: Esta respuesta también puede ayudarte https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29408/como-limitar-la-cantidad-de-decimales-de-un-double/29410#29410

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes usar `setScale` para mostrar el número de decimales que quieras, y además, puedes poner si quieres que lo redondee de mitad hacia arriba o hacia abajo. Aquí un ejemplo de redondeo hacia arriba con dos decimales:

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(3.33333);
bd = bd.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

Para mostrarlo con una `,` en vez de con un `.` puedes convertirlo a `String` y luego sustituir el `.` por una `,`:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texto);
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(3.33333);
tv.setText(bd.toString().replace(",","."));
```

Comment: En las líneas en las que haces el `setScale` tienes que asignarselo a la variable. Es decir: `aux1 = aux1.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);`

Comment: A la hora de asignar los TextView tienes que hacerlo de la siguiente manera: `tres.setText(aux1.toString().replace(".",",") + " " + "es el 5%");`

Comment: Ahora sí! Una ultima duda que me queda, cómo sería para que el redondeo sea exacto? Es decir. si la tercera cifra fuese 5 o superior el redondeo sea hacia arriba pero si es inferior sea hacia abajo?, Ejemplo: 1,433 (redondeo 1.43), pero si es 1,435 (redondeo 1.44)

Comment: @UserNameYo Editado. Usando `RoundingMode.HALF_UP`

Comment: Solucionado! Muchas gracias @cnbandicoot ! :)