# ¿ Cómo puedo hacer que salgan dos cifras en un JTextField?

Tags: java

Quisiera saber como puedo modificar esta parte del código para que en mi `JTextField` salga a dos cifras, probé con el `DecimalFormat` pero no sé donde implementarlo o como implementarlo

```
 public void CalcularIMC(double altura, double peso)
 {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    imc = peso/(altura*altura);
    ResultadoIMC.setText(String.valueOf(imc));
 }
```

Comment: Posible duplicado [Limitar cantidad de decimales de un Double](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29408/como-limitar-la-cantidad-de-decimales-de-un-double/29410#29410) , en una línea sería `ResultadoIMC.setText(String.format("%.2f", (peso/(altura*altura))));`

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que lo que tratas de hacer es concatenar la salida, si es asi, utiliza un signo "+"para concatenar el siguiente string. Ej:

```
String.valueof(int1) + String.valueof(int2)
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.