# Mostrar número con dos decimales

Tags: java

Tengo un número entero que divido por 100, mostrando el resultado en pantalla, de lo que puedo obtener salidas como:

```
91,32
5,22
11,5
```

Necesito tener siempre dos decimales, por tanto rellenar con ceros en caso de que solo tenga 1, para obtener por ejemplo:

```
91,32
5,22
11,50
```

Para obtener los decimales convierto el número entero inicial en float, es decir, estoy haciendo algo así:

```
int i = 150;
float res, f = (float) i;
res = f / 100;

System.out.println( res );
```

**Editado:**
Para que se entienda, lo voy a usar en un programa que muestra una salida como esta:

```
Contenido total: 126,59€
Hay 49 monedas de 1 cent. Con un valor de: 0,49€
Hay 45 monedas de 2 cent. Con un valor de: 0,90€
Hay 10 monedas de 5 cent. Con un valor de: 0,50€
Hay 14 monedas de 10 cent. Con un valor de: 1,40€
Hay 39 monedas de 20 cent. Con un valor de: 7,80€
Hay 13 monedas de 50 cent. Con un valor de: 6,50€
Hay 27 monedas de 100 cent. Con un valor de: 27,00€
Hay 41 monedas de 200 cent. Con un valor de: 82,00€
```

Aunque no lo había incluido en la pregunta originalmente, también se requiere la parte entera, aunque tenga el valor 0, es decir que `,40` no sería válido, se requeriría: `0,40`.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Como limitar la cantidad de decimales de un double?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29408/como-limitar-la-cantidad-de-decimales-de-un-double)

Comment: @Dev. Joel creo que no es lo misma pregunta, aunque la solución que diste habría resuelto mi problema. Yo necesitaba mostrar dos decimales, aunque hubiera 1 (o ninguno), mas que un redondeo o limitar los decimales, es decir, rellenar con ceros, por ello era muy importante una solución concreta, probe en algún momento con **DecimalFormat** y el patrón ´"#.##"´ pero no daba el resultado esperado.

Comment: Con `String.format` lo veo funcionando perfectamente, lo he tomado del link que está en el comentario anterior: [Ejemplo](https://ideone.com/TKUBPJ).

Comment: No es duplicado, con lo que comenta Dev.Joel solo redondea cuando se tienen mas decimales, por ejemplo 12.546 redondea a 12.54 pero 12.5 solo queda como 12.5 y no como 12.50 como desea el OP @Orici

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Puedes usar este formato:

```
 DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
 String resultado = df.format(valor)
```

o también:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00"); :
```

de esta forma entonces siempre obtendrías 2 decimales.

Puedes usar lo anterior en un método:

```
   private static String getTwoDecimals(double value){
      DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00"); 
      return df.format(value);
    }
```

---

Por ejemplo si definimos estos valores:

```
91.32
5.22
11.5
1.2
2.6
```

Usando el método se obtiene:

```
91.32
5.22
11.50
1.20
2.60
```

[**ver demo online.**](https://www.ideone.com/jJGyRa)

Answer (score 3):

Como se ha comentado antes, puedes utilizar `DecimalFormat`, pero también se puede hacer directamente con la clase `String`.

```
float f = 1.4851485F;
String resultado = String.format("%.2f", f);
System.out.println(resultado);
```

La salida que obtengo en ambos casos es

```
1,49
```

Entonces he sustituido la coma por un punto.

```
System.out.println(resultado.replace(",", "."));
```

Obteniendo el resultado con punto en vez de coma.

```
1.49
```

Comment: Esto también funciona, por ejemplo para 11.0F se obtiene 11.00 para 11.5, se obtiene 11.50.

Answer (score 2):

Intenta esto:

```
double monto = 200.3456;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");      
monto = Double.valueOf(df.format(monto));

System.out.println(monto); // 200.35
```

Comment: Quiere 2 decimales, de 11.5 requiere 11.50

Comment: 0.00 es un mejor patron?

Comment: Si pueden establecer el siguiente formato   DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

Comment: @gbianchi si!! ese si funcionaría!

Comment: Ok, funciona si usas el patrón ´"#.00"´, puedes editar tu respuesta para incluir la solución correcta.