# ¿Como formatear un string a 2 decimales Java?

Tags: java, string

Les explico:

Tengo un `String` en **Java**:

```
String numero = "59.2348837";
```

esto es lo que intento realizar:

```
String.format( "%.2f", numero)
```

E intento obtener como resultado:

```
String resultado = "59.23";
```

Pero me lanza un error porque **numero** es `String`. El error salta cuando hago el `string format`.

**¿Cómo podría formatear ese `String` a 2 decimales y que el resultado
siga siendo un `String`?.**

Comment: Y si haces el cast antes de enviar el parámetro ?  es decir `String.format( "%.2f", Float.parseFloat(numero))`  también hay [una pregunta relacionada por si te interesa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29408/como-limitar-la-cantidad-de-decimales-de-un-double/29410#29410)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

te marca error "numero es String", ya que  necesitas convertir el String a un valor numérico, lo puedes realizar de esta forma convirtiendo el valor de `String` a `Double` o `Float`  mediante `Double.parseDouble(numero)` o mediante `Float.parseFloat(numero)`:

```
String numero = "59.2348837";

String resultado = String.format( "%.2f", Float.parseFloat(numero));
```

Existe una pregunta similar

[Mostrar número con dos decimales](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/144301/mostrar-n%C3%BAmero-con-dos-decimales?noredirect=1&lq=1)

pero en este caso puedes convertir el valor de String a Double mediante `Double.parseDouble(numero)`, ejemplo:

```
   String numero = "59.2348837";

   DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
   String resultado = df.format(Double.parseDouble(numero));
```

resultado tendrá el valor :

```
59.23
```

---

Puedes incluso usar un método con lo descrito anteriormente para obtener el valor que requieres:

```
private static String getTwoDecimals(String valor){
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    return df.format(Double.parseDouble(valor));
}
```

y lo llamas de esta forma:

```
String numero = "59.2348837";
String resultado = getTwoDecimals(numero);
```

para obtener como valor de resultado:

```
59.23
```

Answer (score 2):

Es debido a que el formato `%.2f` es permitido para float. Para formatearlos tendrás que convertir el `string` a `float` y luego darle formato:

```
String numero = "59.2348837";
String result = String.format( "%.2f", Float.parseFloat(numero)); // <- convertiendo el string a float
System.out.println(result); // 59.23
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema que estás teniendo se debe a que en la cadena de formato, le estás diciendo al método `String.format()` que lo que recibirá como primer parámetro es un número flotante y al pasarle un `String` te debe lanzar una excepción similar a esta:

```
`java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String`
```

Para solventar esto, solo debes convertir tu cadena a un número flotante (float o double) y pasarle ese número al método. De esta forma te sirve:

```
String numero = "59.2348837";
String numeroFormateado = String.format("%.2f", Double.parseDouble(numero));
```

Answer (score 1):

Si solo quieres 2 decimales tambien puedes hacer un substring así te ahorras el doble parseo de String a double y de double a String

Te pongo un ejemplo rápido:

```
// Aqui tenemos el número
String numero = "100.9988" 

// Despues obtenemos la posición del punto
int posicionPunto = numero.indexOf('.'); 

// Seguidamente coges solo lo que te interesa del String desde el inicio hasta los2 decimales
// Le sumamos 3 a posicionPunto para que avance 3 posiciones (1 Punto y 2 Decimales)
resultado = numero.subString(0,posicionPunto+3)
```