# Java solo 2 decimales

Tags: java

Tengo este codigo, donde hago la suma de una columna de un jtable, pero tengo un problema, que deseo limitar la cantidad de decimales que sale pero no lo consegui. Probe con el DecimalFormat, pero lo corri y no suma nada sale como resultado 0, de una columna que si tiene datos. Alguna sugerencia o ayuda?

```
txtSuma.setText("0");
int ta=jReporteGanadores.getRowCount();
int c=0;
do
    try {
        int f=c++;
        double n1=Double.parseDouble(jReporteGanadores.getValueAt(f,5).toString());
        String nu=txtSuma.getText();
        double nu2=Double.parseDouble(nu);
        double n2=Double.parseDouble(txtSuma.getText());
        double re=n1+nu2;//LUGAR A FORMATEAR DECIMALES
        String df=String.valueOf(re);
        int cd=df.indexOf(".");
        String x=df.substring(cd+2);
        if(x.isEmpty()){
            txtSuma.setText(String.valueOf(re+"0"));
        }else{
            String vx=txtSuma.getText();
            double vx2=Double.parseDouble(vx);
            double ref=(double) n1+vx2;
            txtSuma.setText(String.valueOf(ref));
        }    
    }catch(Exception e){
    }
while(c<ta);
```

Comment: cual es el campo que quieres redondear ?

Comment: hola, esta respuesta te puede ayudar https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/29410/93052

Comment: double ref=(double) n1+vx2; este es el campo que quiero redondear

Answer (score 1):

Solo se debes usar, el DecimalFormat despues de hacer la suma:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
double resultado = c1+c2;
df.format(resultado);
```

O puedes usarlo de esta forma:

```
double valorfinal = Math.round(resulado*100d)/100d;
```

Answer (score 0):

Para limitar a solo 2 decimales en caso de ser una variable doble debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
double R=83.13532213;

   R=Math.round(R*100.0)/100.0;
   System.out.print(R);//83.14
```

Así que te recomiendo que el resultado los almacenes en una sola variable doble y apliques `Match.round` como lo hice anteriormente.