# JAVA ¿Como redondear estas decimas? para que salga lo siguiente:

Tags: java, netbeans, redondeo

**Esto debe salir:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Y me sale esto:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Como puedo redondear las ultimas decimas**

**aqui mi codigo**

```
 public void calcularMedia_y_Desviacion()
{

            //varible auxiliar para conocer el tamaño de la lista
              int contador=0;
            //variable auxiliar que guardara la suma de los datos ingresados
              double media=0;
            //variable que guardara la varianza
              double varianza=0;
            //variable que guardar la desviacion estandar
              double desviacion=0;
            //Variable para guardar la sumatoria 
              double sumatoria;
            //Variable para guardar el resultado de la media  
              double resultadoMedia;
            //Cremos un nodo auxiliar para poder recorrer los nodos de la lista
              Nodo recorrer=inicio;
            //Condicion para que mientras recorrer no sea nulo va ir recorriendo la lista
              while (recorrer!=null){
            //Mientras nosea nulo la variable media va ir sumando los datos que se van recorriendo
              media=media+recorrer.dato;
            //con esto va ir al siguiente nodo
              recorrer=recorrer.siguiente;
            //por cada repeticion de la condicion el contador aumentara 1
              contador=contador+1;
                                   }
            //Declaramos una variable para sacar el resultado de la media

            //Realizamos la operacion para sacar la media
              resultadoMedia=media/contador;

            //Cremos un nodo auxiliar para poder recorrer los nodos de la lista
              recorrer=inicio;
            //Condicion para que mientras recorrer no sea nulo va ir recorriendo la lista
              while(recorrer!=null){
            //hacemos la operacion para sacar la sumatoria  
              sumatoria=Math.pow(recorrer.dato-resultadoMedia,2);
            //casa repeticion ira sumando la varianza con la sumatoria obtenida
              varianza=varianza+sumatoria;
            //con esto va ir al siguiente nodo
              recorrer=recorrer.siguiente;
                                  }
            //Realiza la operacion para sacar la varianza
              varianza=varianza/(contador-1);
            //Realizamos la operacion para sacar la desviacion estandar
              desviacion=Math.sqrt(varianza);
            //Mandamos el resultado de la media al usuario
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,("La media es: "+resultadoMedia));
            //Mandamos el resultado de la desviacion estandar al usuario
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,("La desviacion estandar es : "+desviacion));

   }
```

Comment: Usa `DecimalFormat`

Comment: En este link podes encontrar la respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29408/como-limitar-la-cantidad-de-decimales-de-un-double

Comment: @alfap la opcion me me aprece, sera por la baja reputacion que tengo?, dejo esto en sus manos :D