# poner limite de caracteres a un atributo double con 8 enteros y 2 decimales

Tags: java, sql

Tengo una base de datos con un atributo peso y tiene que tener 8 enteros comoo maximo y 2 decimales. Mi problema es que se poner el tamaño total pero no por separado.  Esto es lo que yo podria aunque esta mal porque toma el total y no cada cosa

```
public void setPeso(double peso) {
     if (Double.toString(peso).length() <= 10)
        this.peso = peso;
    }
```

Comment: En base a los decimales, esto te puede ayudar [¿Como limitar la cantidad de decimales de un double?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29408/como-limitar-la-cantidad-de-decimales-de-un-double).

Comment: eso es para la salida yo quiero para setearlo es diferente

Comment: En ese caso, modifica tu pregunta para que se comprenda mejor lo que estas buscando.

Comment: si tiene 8 enteros y dos decimales y viene de una base de datos, porque simplemente no comprobar que, **como numero** sea menor a 100000000? O tal vez estoy entendiendo mal algo...

Answer (score 1):

lo primero que se me ocurre, es que puedes crear una función para esto, parecido a esto

```
public bool isDoubleFormat(double n){
   string a=String.ValueOf(n);
   //considerando que es un doble, siempre tendrá un "." y siempre tendrá un antes y después en ese "."
   string[] partes=a.Split(".");
   if (partes[0].Length<=8 && partes[1].Length<=2){
     return true;
   }else{
     return false;
   }
}
```

El método que construí, convierte tu double a string, y usa la función split para partirlo en el punto, dando como resultado dos partes, por ejemplo:

> 150.65 = "150" "65"

Siempre van a quedar dos partes, así que las evaluamos directamente:

> `if (partes[0].Length<=8 && partes[1].Length<=2)`

Finalmente, devolvemos un booleano que indica si corresponde al tamaño deseado.
En tu método, lo puedes llamar de esta manera:

```
public void setPeso(double peso) {
     if (isDoubleFormat(peso)){
        this.peso = peso;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Puedes usar esta expresión regular

```
\d{1,8}(\.\d{1,2})?
```

Comment: no tiene mala pinta pero eso como lo meto en el set?

Comment: Gracias por tomar el tiempo en responder, siempre es mejor agregar respuestas mas completas que no necesiten ser aclaradas. Por favor edita tu respuesta. Te invito a que revises [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)