# Redondeo en java decimales

Tags: java

Estoy trando de redondear una cantidad luego de sacar un por cierto en java para compara con otro resultado 
1072.03 * 0.18

```
Math.floor(1072.03 * 0.18); 
 //Output 192.9654
```

Esta es la caridad quiero salga cuando rendonde el resultado luego de sacar el porcentaje

```
//Output 192.97
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta manera funcionaría:

```
double roundOff = Math.round(mivalor * 100.0) / 100.0;
```

El resultado sería:

```
123.14
```

Para tu ejemplo el código sería el siguiente:

```
 double roundOff = Math.round(1072.03 * 0.18 * 100.0) / 100.0;
```

Answer (score 4):

Puedes utilizar algo así

```
 DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
 System.out.println(df.format(number));
```

te dejo la referencia por si te sirve.
[¿Como limitar la cantidad de decimales de un double?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29408/como-limitar-la-cantidad-de-decimales-de-un-double)

Answer (score 1):

Hola me invente esta forma de resolver tu problema espero te ayude

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Double Num1,Num2,Resultado; //Declaro Resultado
        int Decimales=100; //1 cero por cada decima que quieras

        Num1=1072.03;
        Num2=0.18;

        Resultado=Num1*Num2; //Saco Cuenta ->192.9654
        Resultado=Resultado*Decimales; //-> 19296.54 Convierto en entero lo que quiero que se quede
        Resultado=(double)Math.round(Resultado); //->19297 Elimino el resto
        Resultado=Resultado/Decimales; //Vuelvo a convertir a decimales lo que quiero que se quede
        System.out.println(Resultado); //Output 192.9654)
    }
```

}

Lo converti en funcion para hacerlo mas facil usarlo

Para llamarlo usas esto

```
`Resultado=redondear(Num,Decimales);`
```

siendo Num el numero que quieres redondear y Decimales la cantidad de decimales que quieras

```
public static double redondear (double Num, int Decimales){
    int aux=1;
    for (int i=0;i<Decimales;i++){
        aux=aux*10;
    }
    Num=Num*aux;
    Num=(double)Math.round(Num);
    Num=Num/aux; 
    return(Num);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para trabajar con decimales, te recomendaría usar BigDecimal, que tiene mejor precisión que Double.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Redondeo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigDecimal numero= new BigDecimal("1072.03");
    BigDecimal porcentaje = new BigDecimal("0.18");
    BigDecimal resultado = numero.multiply(porcentaje);
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
    System.out.println(df.format(resultado));
  }
}
```

Para mostrar dos decimales, puedes usar la solución que te indica 
@E.Rawrdríguez.Ophanim

Answer (score 0):

Hace tiempos había publicado un resultado similar a lo que necesitas por si te interesa:

[¿Como limitar la cantidad de decimales de un double?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29408/como-limitar-la-cantidad-de-decimales-de-un-double/160971#160971)

el método lo puedes copiar y pegar y utilizar las veces que quieras.

```
numero: el valor con todos los decimales

numeroDecimales: cuantos decimales quiero recuperar

Ejem: 2.8049999999999997 devuelve 2.805

double val = formatearDecimales( 2.8049999999999997, 3);

public static Double formatearDecimales(Double numero, Integer numeroDecimales) {
return Math.round(numero * Math.pow(10, numeroDecimales)) / Math.pow(10, numeroDecimales);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta función te va a servir exactamente para lo que quieres...

```
 private static double redondea(double x) {
                double y = (int)(x * 100D);
                double z = (int)Math.ceil(x * 1000D);
                if(z % 10D > 5D)
                    y = (y + 1.0D) / 100D;
                else
                    y /= 100D;
                return y;
 }
System.out.println(redondea(192.9654)); //192.97
```

Comment: No es muy recomendado usar double cuando se quiere trabajar con decimales