# Quitarle digitos a una cadena

Tags: java, float

Hola estoy haciendo un programa  en JAVA para sacar calificaciones, pero al sacar el resultado sale mas digitos decimales de los que yo quiero, por ejemplo:

Resultado: **9.40001**

Lo que yo quiero que se muestre es:

Resultado: **9.4**

El float pone todos los digitos y supongo que debo de poner
este es el codigo;

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
if(e.getSource() == sacaresultado){
float primerparcial = 0, segundoparcial = 0, tercerparcial = 0, resultado = 0;
     
primerparcial = Float.parseFloat(escribirprimer.getText());
segundoparcial = Float.parseFloat(escribirsegundo.getText());
tercerparcial = Float.parseFloat(escribirtercero.getText());
     
resultado = (primerparcial + segundoparcial + tercerparcial) / 3;
     
resultadodelabeca.setText("resultado: " + resultado);
}
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! debes pasarle un formato numerico a la cadena de salida ;)

Comment: Probablemente se podría marcar como duplicada de [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29408/como-limitar-la-cantidad-de-decimales-de-un-double)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como limitar la cantidad de decimales de un double?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29408/como-limitar-la-cantidad-de-decimales-de-un-double)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Por qué mis programas no pueden hacer cálculos aritméticos correctamente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197/por-qu%c3%a9-mis-programas-no-pueden-hacer-c%c3%a1lculos-aritm%c3%a9ticos-correctamente)

Answer (score 0):

```
String r = String.format("%.1f", resultado).replace(",", ".");
```

luego imprimes r el cual será 9.4

el 1 numero de %.1f es  la cantidad de dígitos después de la coma, y el replace es porque el string queda con una coma y no con el punto decimal

y si necesitas volverlo float de nuevo entonces parsealo

```
float resultadoNuevo = Float.parseFloat(r);
```

y seguirá teniendo el 9.4