# error de calculo en operacion con Double.parseDouble()

Tags: java

hola tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
String precio="3.8";
int unidades=3;
double total=Double.parseDouble(precio)*unidades;
System.out.println(total);
```

que me devuelve: 11.399999999999999, lo cual es incorrecto porque deberia devolver 11.4. ¿como puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0):

La salida es correcta,por que estas haciendo uso de una variable tipo double y por eso te la devuelve de esa manera(mayor precisión),si quieres aproximarla para obtener la salida que quieres pues hacerlo Mediante [Math.Round()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(double)) donde la cantidad de ceros es la cantidad de decimales a limitar

```
String precio="3.8";
int unidades=3;
double total=Math.round(Double.parseDouble(precio)*unidades*100)/100.0;
System.out.println(total);
```

[aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29408/como-limitar-la-cantidad-de-decimales-de-un-double/29410#29410) hay otras maneras de hacerlo

de lo contrario lo correcto es  usar float en vez de double

```
float total=Float.parseFloat(precio)*unidades;
```

double es más preciso pero está codificado en 8 bytes. float tiene solo 4 bytes, por lo que tiene menos espacio y menos precisión. ;)

Comment: vale me sirvio, pero lo que no entiendo es por que dices que es correcto, ya que si sumas 3.8+3.8+3.8 da 11.4 exactos.

Comment: la salida de una variable de tipo `double` siempre te devolverá un excedente de decimales que vendría a ser el equivalente a un numero redondeado a 1 o 2 decimales.... si tu aproximas 11.399999 el valor sera 11.4

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta es click en check ✓