# Mostrar número con dos decimales en java

Tags: java

Estoy viendo un curso en YT para aprender Java en el ejemplo del video enseña como mostrar un número, pero solo con dos decimales mostrándolo en consola, pero yo estoy queriéndolo hacer con mensajes en pantalla, ¿hay alguna manera mostrar el resultado del caso 4 solo con dos decimales?

```
String figura = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Elige una opcion: \n1: Cuadrado \n2: Rectangulo \n3: Triangulo \n4: Circulo ");

    int  x = Integer.parseInt(figura);

    switch(x){
        case 1: 
        int lado = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce el lado"));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El area del cuadrado es: " + Math.pow(lado, 2));
        break;

        case 2:
        int base = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce la base"));
        int altura = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce la altura"));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El area del rectangulo es: " + base *altura);
        break;

        case 3:
        base = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce la base"));
        altura = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce la altura"));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El area del triangulo es: " + (base * altura) / 2);
        break;

        case 4:
        int radio = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce el radio"));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El area del circulo es: " + Math.PI*(Math.pow(radio, 2)));


    }
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29408/como-limitar-la-cantidad-de-decimales-de-un-double

Comment: Eso me ayudo a ver mas maneras de limitar los decimales pero al mostrarlo en System.out.println en la consola pero no entiendo como hacerlo en JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El area del circulo es: " + Math.PI*(Math.pow(radio, 2)));

Comment: ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre println y showMessageDialog?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como limitar la cantidad de decimales de un double?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29408/como-limitar-la-cantidad-de-decimales-de-un-double)

Comment: podrias usar el metodo round de la misma clase Math `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El area del circulo es: " +Math.round(Math.PI*(Math.pow(radio, 2))*100)/100d);`

Answer (score 0):

//Podrías: Inicialmente importar la clase java.text

import java.text.*;

/*Posteriormente creamos el objeto df para dar formato a los decimales:
Agregando cuanto decimales necesites en: ("#0.00") o ("#0.000") o ("#0.0000")...

Area del circulo formula: Pi * (radio ^ 2)*/

case 4:

```
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.000");
        
        int radio = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa el radio del circulo"));
                                
        JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog(null, ("El área del circulo es " + df.format(Math.PI*(Math.pow(radio, 2)))) );
        
        break;
```